# How to Matlab to send TTL signal via BNC ports?

Tags: matlab, ttl

I’m trying to use Matlab to control 8-channel perfusion device. The manual said that on the back of the device there are 8 BNC type connection ports for transmitting TTL signal to control the on/off of the 8 channels, respectively. How to use Matlab to control these 8 BNC ports to send TTL input? What accessories should I purchase?

There is also another single input port--analog input. The manual said it is an BNC connector to apply an analog signal to switch individual channels using Analog Discriminator. By varing the ampitude of signal, different channels will be triggered. Can Matlab control this analog input?

Thanks

Comment: This is completely dependent on the device hardware and what driver or API it possesses. Nobody can help you without this information.

Comment: I have found a solution: use arduino uno to send TTL